# Formula not translating correctly when changing variables

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I'm reverse engineering this Python formula for finding the sum of a range of numbers times pi squared, but it only works when the variable "3" is inserted, and I can't seem to figure out why...

For range of 3, the algorithm matches up with pythons sum function:

```
>>> sum(math.pow(i*pi,2) for i in range(1,3+1))
138.174461615251
>>> ((3*pi)*(3*pi) + (4*pi)*(4*pi)+(3*pi*pi))/2
138.174461615251
```

But any other variable produces a drastically different result:

```
>>> sum(math.pow(i*pi,2) for i in range(1,10+1))
3799.797694419403
>>> ((10*pi)*(10*pi) + (11*pi)*(11*pi)+(10*pi*pi))/2
1139.9393083258208
```

Excuse my mathematical illiteracy, but could someone help me understand why I'm getting these results?

Comment: Why do ou think this answer is wrong ?

Comment: @john i'm still working on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you use doesn't make any sense:

```
sum (i * pi) ^ 2 for i = 1 to n       =
(pi ^ 2) * (sum i ^ 2 for i = 1 to n)
```

`sum i ^ 2 for i = 1 to n` equals:

[image]

And you don't use anything similar.

Here is my code:

```
import math

def slow(n):
    return sum((i * math.pi) ** 2 for i in range(1, n + 1))

def fast(n):
    return math.pi ** 2 * n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6

print(slow(10)) #=> 3799.79769442
print(fast(10)) #=> 3799.79769442
```

Comment: Well, hold on. Each time I try and enter your formula you go and change it.

Comment: Yes, that does work. Would you recommend any materials I can study to learn these formulas?

Comment: Well, I better get to work then. Thanks for your help